# All possible ways to do apps that work for iPhone/iPad apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I need to develop some app for iPad and iPhone users.

I understand that there are 3 ways:

1. `Two distinct Apps`, one for iPhone and one for iPad. (Not linked in apple store)
2. `One Universal app` (appear with `+` sign in Apple Store, the app store choose the desired app depending on the device) (I choose from xcode to make the app `Universal`).
3. `One application with two targets`, One for iPhone and one for iPad. (using Duplicate target for iPad in xcode) (Linked in apple store).

I need to understand the differences between 2 and 3 above.

Thanks.

Comment: 2. Is one application that runs on both platform. 1 & 3 are the same, the only difference is in 3 you'd use one Xcode project whereas with 1 you would use two. With both 1 & 3 you would still have two separate apps on the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in 2 you are creating one single binary from one Xcode project that works on both iPad and iPhone. It has a universal target meaning it runs on both iPad and iPhone requiring you to adapt the user interface appropriately.

In 3 I believe you are implying that you create one Xcode project and create two build targets inside the project. I have done this before and it allows you to easily share files between applications. Just add references to the files you want to share in both targets. As far as how 3 looks in the AppStore it looks the same as 1, two separate applications.